# Reading User Input in a Makefile Script

Tags: shell, makefile

I have a very simple Makefile (that just recursively calls another subdirectory make):

```
all:
    cd addons/godot-haskell-plugin && make && cd -
run:
    cd addons/godot-haskell-plugin && make run && cd -
```

What I'd like to do is

1. Check if shell variable `ENV_VAR` is defined.
2. If it is, then run the Makefile as usual (i.e., `ENV_VAR=1 make all` should do exactly as `make all` above).
3. If it isn't, then prompt the user with a message "Warning: ENV_VAR isn't defined; continue? [Y/n]", where an input of "Y" passes `make all` and `make run` as usual, and an input of "n" simply echos a message and exits.

I know that to do this in bash you would use a combination of `echo` and `read` functions. But it's unclear how to do this in Make.

Comment: If you know how to do it in `bash`, use `bash`, i.e. `bash -c "..."`

Comment: For future reference, a good question should not be layered like an onion. If you want to know how to read user input in a makefile, ask that; your question asks how to do that *and* branch the build on the result, *and* have the whole thing conditional on an environmental variable.

Comment: Note that if you do this you cannot use parallel mode in GNU make (`-j`).  Since jobs are running in parallel only one will be given stdin and you can't know which one.

Comment: @MadScientist: I hadn't thought of that. There might be a way around that, but it would probably be wiser to rethink the entire project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make isn't really intended to be interactive, but you can kludge it.

There's more than one way to do it, but since you seem to want this behavior to be specific to some targets (`all` and `run`), I'd add a PHONY target that interacts with the user and perhaps aborts Make:

```
all run: check

.PHONY: check
check:
ifndef ENV_VAR
    @echo Warning: ENV_VAR isn\'t defined\; continue? [Y/n]
    @read line; if [ $$line = "n" ]; then echo aborting; exit 1 ; fi
endif
```

Note that I'm using a Make conditional for one variable, and a bash conditional for the other. You can use either for either, but in this case this is the cleanest way.

Comment: Elegant solution given the constraints. Is there a more idiomatic way to do it without make (not necessary to answer just in case you know of one I'm curious)?

Comment: @George: I'm not sure what you mean by "more idiomatic", but you certainly can do it without Make. For example, you could use a bash script with nested conditionals.

Comment: it should be compared like this
`@read line; if [ $$line = "n" ]; then echo aborting; exit 1 ; fi`

otherwise POSIX sh will not understand `==` for string equality,

Comment: @AndrzejPiszczek: Good catch, thank you! I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

This might actually be the *opposite* of what [George was asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245838/reading-user-input-in-a-makefile-script#comment91468506_52248926), but here's a version that could qualify as "more idiomatic" in the sense of more make built-ins, less shell script:

```
all:
ifeq ($(ENV_VAR),)
    $(error Need a value for ENV_VAR, e.g., make <target> ENV_VAR=value)
endif
    cd addons/godot-haskell-plugin && make && cd -
run:
    cd addons/godot-haskell-plugin && make run && cd -
```

It's probably best to avoid `read`ing within a Makefile for reasons mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60253549/785213), but I very much like the method of `make target VAR=value` because it finds middle ground between hard-coding everything, or prompting for everything with heaps of gnarly shell script.

Note that `ifndef` probably wouldn't do what you expect here. Quoting from [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html) (emphasis mine):

> Note that `ifdef` only tests whether a variable has a value. **It does not expand the variable to see if that value is nonempty.** Consequently, tests using `ifdef` return true for all definitions except those like `foo =`. To test for an empty value, use `ifeq ($(foo),)`.

The behavior described above is the same for `ifndef`, hence the `ifeq` which test against the empty string instead.

Hope that helps.