# Interactive input of a Makefile variable

Tags: makefile, gnu

I want to run makefile with input variable. What I want is that if I write down the project name, a folder with that name will be created.

So I write `read` command:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -W -Wall
FILE := hi
src = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ = $(src:.c=.o)

all : $(FILE)
$(FILE) : $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

.PHONY: clean

clean : 
    rm *.o $(FILE)

move : 
    mkdir -p ../../bin/$(FILE);
    mkdir -p ../../exe/$(FILE);
    mv *.o ../../bin/$(FILE);
    mv $(FILE) ../../exe/$(FILE)

afterclean :
    rm ../../bin/$(FILE)/*.o;
    rm ../../exe/$(FILE)/$(FILE)

execute :
    ./../../exe/$(FILE)/$(FILE)


read :
    @read -p "Enter : " enter; \
    $(FILE) := enter; \
    echo $FILE
```

What I wanna do is if I get `FILE` name through `read` I want to change `FILE` variable, but I can't change it. How can I do that?

Comment: Rather than using `read`, consider just running the makefile with `make FILE=whatever`.

Comment: but if i do like that i should always write FILE= command even when i want to clean

Comment: @AlphaCode Your problem is that you want two rather distinct functionalities in one makefile: for one the creation of a new project and on the other hand the build of that project. Now, make (and most other software construction tools) do not work with a single-phase script like the one you are imagining, they rather strictly separate creation of a project from building. Most of the time the build process is tightly tailored to the specific project and needs the configuration to make any sense. This is not surprising as the project at this point doesn't change much, except uniformly growing.

Comment: What you're asking to do _can_ be done in the scope of a single recipe, using shell syntax, as long as you're careful with your semicolons and backslashes, and you're sure to "escape" the `$`s as `$$`. But there's no way to have a recipe reach back up and change the value of a top-level Makefile variable, like you're expecting to do here. Hence @HolyBlackCat's advice.

Comment: @TheDudeAbides You can change a global variable with `$(eval)`. It's just not a good thing to do.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ah, I love it when "there's no way to…" turns into "there's a _way_ to, but…" `;)` Updated my answer below to include this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Well in short, you cannot easily do that (and you should likely not want to, scroll down for rationale). If you have a closer look at your `Makefile` you'd notice that you're mixing `make` and shell syntax... and their contexts.

In your case, it literally passes the following string to shell (value of `SHELL`, likely defaults to `/bin/sh`) with `-c`:

```
read -p "Enter : " enter; \
hi := enter; \
echo ILE
```

Which shows the effects of the intermixed syntax. `$(FILE)` (value `hi`) and `$F` (unset -> empty) are make variables substituted by make before invoking shell. (while `read` into `enter` variable is not used at all and instead literal string `enter` is used in attempted make variable assignment inside that running shell.)

If you wanted to run a shell command and assign a value from what it has done / learned to a make variable, you would have to do so using `shell` function (or generate a (temporary) file you would `include`, but that's even messier):

```
FILE := $(shell read -p "Enter: " enter ; echo $${enter})
```

That however always asks... unless you use conditional assignment (`?=`) in which case you could choose already from the command line (`make FILE=something`, at which point we're about to close the circle). I am generally unsure what your intentions were how to tell `make` when to ask and when to use default value of `hi`.

That leads me to why this notion sounds suspect to me to start with and why suggestion made by [@HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat) is a superior way of customizing invocation of `make`.

Also any runtime user interactions generally break automation (which is what we have `make` for) and also make builds non-reproducible. So, they better are to be avoided.

In other words, if you really had to, I'd say write an `interactive_make_call.sh` around it for this type of invocation:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter : " enter
make FILE="${enter}" "$@"
```

Or even:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter : " enter
if [[ -n "${enter}" ]] ; then
        make FILE="${enter}" "$@"
else
        make "$@"
fi
```

To fallback on the default value of `FILE` from the `Makefile` if you just press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for ur advice. I solved problem with your interactive_make_call.sh

Comment: That adding interactivity to a Makefile is not "what make is 'for'" _is_ a valid point. But if you're using `make` to do some light dependency management on top of shell script, and you totally _intend_ to have it be run interactively, by humans, then what the OP is asking for is [definitely possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52248926).

Answer (score 1):

This is not so much an answer to the original poster's question as a clarification: yes, it *is* possible to read user input within a Makefile recipe. You just can't expect the values read from `read` to propagate to other recipes in the Makefile without contortions like `$(eval …)`, or writing to a temp file or something like that.

Here's working syntax for what the OP was trying to accomplish in the `read` target, with the caveat mentioned above:

```
read :
    @read -p "Enter : " enter; \
    echo $$enter
```

Recall that make's default behavior is to run each line of a recipe in its own shell; as a side effect, the value of `$enter` loses scope after the semicolon-backslashes stop. So its lifetime is only within that single statement in the Makefile.

Bonus bit of trivia: if you've defined `SHELL = bash` already, then there's no essential need to assign a variable to hold the reply; the environment variable `REPLY` is used by default. This is not true of [the Bourne shell](https://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh/sh.1.html), however, and I can't speak for other shells.